# Connect a python aplication with dynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running a Python application in Elastic Beanstalk for test, but how to connect the application to DynamoDB or other Databases?

The application uses Flask FrameWork and html/css:

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

To interact with DynanoDB you would have to use AWS SDK [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) in your flask application.

Also, you would need to setup [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for your EB instance(s) with the permissions to access the DynamoDB table.

If you have your EB in private subnets, you would have to also use either NAT gateway or VPC gateway endpoint for DynamoDB to enable connectivity between your EB instances and the DynamoDB service.